# Dealing with singular fit in mixed models

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, overfitting, singular-matrix

Let's say we have a model

```
mod <- Y ~ X*Condition + (X*Condition|subject)

# Y = logit variable  
# X = continuous variable  
# Condition = values A and B, dummy coded; the design is repeated 
#             so all participants go through both Conditions  
# subject = random effects for different subjects 

summary(model)
Random effects:
 Groups  Name             Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 subject (Intercept)      0.85052  0.9222                    
         X                0.08427  0.2903   -1.00            
         ConditionB       0.54367  0.7373   -0.37  0.37      
         X:ConditionB     0.14812  0.3849    0.26 -0.26 -0.56
Number of obs: 39401, groups:  subject, 219

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.49686    0.06909   36.14  < 2e-16 ***
X                -1.03854    0.03812  -27.24  < 2e-16 ***
ConditionB       -0.19707    0.06382   -3.09  0.00202 ** 
X:ConditionB      0.22809    0.05356    4.26 2.06e-05 ***
```

Here we observe a singular fit, because the correlation between intercept and x random effects is -1. Now, according to [this helpful link](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1) one way to deal with this model is to remove higher-order random effects (e.g., X:ConditionB) and see whether that makes a difference when testing for singularity. The other is to use the Bayesian approach, e.g., the `blme` package to avoid singularity.

What is the preferred method and why?

I am asking this because using the first or the second one leads to different results - in the first case, I will remove the X:ConditionB random effect and won't be able to estimate the correlation between X and X:ConditionB random effects. On the other hand, using `blme` allows me to keep X:ConditionB and to estimate the given correlation. I see no reason why I should even use the non-bayesian estimations and remove random effects when singular fits occur when I can estimate everything with the Bayesian approach.

Can someone explain to me the benefits and problems using either method to deal with singular fits?

Comment: What are you worried about that corr = -1? It is correlation between random effects.

Comment: So each subject gives you two measurements of Y, one under condition A and one under condition B? If that is true, can you also tell us whether the value of the continuous variable X changes for any given subject between conditions A and B?

Comment: Why do you put Condition in the random effects? Have you tested if it is required?

Comment: @user158565 yes but it indicates singuarity...

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Indeed. Yes it does, x changes for any given subject between A and B. Furthermore, there is theoretical reason to assume that the regression of Y on X is different for every subject

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos It is theoretically feasible. You mean with likelihood ratio test?

Comment: @User33268 yes, I mean with a likelihood ratio test, because even if theoretically is feasible, it may be not supported by the data.

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos this is why I ask why Bayesian framework offers a fit which is not singular. How can I know whether singular fit in lme4 occured because the data does not support the hypothesis, or because the fitting method is not powerful enough?

Comment: You should write down the variance-covariance matrix for a single subject based on your model, then see if it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you obtain a singular fit, this is often indicating that the model is overfitted – that is, the random effects structure is too complex to be supported by the data, which naturally leads to the advice to remove the most complex part of the random effects structure (usually random slopes).  The benefit of this approach is that it leads to a more parsimonious model that is not over-fitted.

However, before doing anything, do you have a good reason for wanting `X`, `Condition` and their interaction, all to vary by subject in the first place ? Does the theory of how the data are generated suggest this ?

If you desire to fit the model with the maximal random effects structure, and `lme4` obtains a singular fit, then fitting the same model in a Bayesian framework might very well inform you *why* `lme4` had problems, by inspecting trace plots and how well the various parameter estimates converge. The advantage in taking the Bayesian approach is that by doing so you may uncover a problem with original model ie. the reason why the maximum random effects structure isn’t supported by the data) or it might uncover why `lme4` is unable to fit the model. I have encountered situations where a Bayesian model does not converge well, unless informative priors are used – which may or may not be OK.

In short, both approaches have merit.

However, I would always start from a place where the initial model is parsimonious and informed by expert domain knowledge to determine the most appropriate random effects structure. Specifying grouping variables is relatively easy, but random slopes usually don’t *have* to be included. Only include them if they make sound theoretical sense AND they are supported by the data.

Edit:
It is mentioned in the comments that there are sound theoretical reasons to fit the maximal random effects structure. So, a relatively easy way to proceed with an equivalent Bayesian model is to swap the call to `glmer` with `stan_glmer` from the `rstanarm` package – it is designed to be plug and play.  It has default priors, so you can quickly get a model fitted. The package also has many tools for assessing convergence. If you find that all the parameters have converging to plausible values, then you are all good. However there can be a number of issues – for example a variance being estimated at or below zero, or an estimate that continues to drift. The mc-stan.org site has a wealth of information and a user forum.

Comment: Yes, I have good theoretical reasons to assume that the regression of Y on X should vary across subjects differently for condition A and B. The regression implies processing style.

Can you give me some more info on how to interpret trace plots as a diagnostic tool for singularity causes?

Answer (score 29):

This is a very interesting thread, with interesting answers and comments! Since this hasn't been brought up yet, I wanted to point out that we have very little data for each subject (as I understand it).  Indeed, each subject has only two values for each of the response variable Y, categorical variable Condition and continuous variable X.  In particular, we know that the two values of Condition are A and B.

If we were to pursue the two-stage regression modelling instead of the mixed effects modelling, we couldn't even fit a linear regression model to the data from a specific subject, as illustrated in the toy example below for one of the subject:

```
y <- c(4, 7)
condition <- c("A", "B")
condition <- factor(condition)
x <- c(0.2, 0.4)

m <- lm(y ~ condition*x)
summary(m)
```

The output of this subject-specific model would be:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ condition * x)

Residuals:
ALL 2 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         4         NA      NA       NA
conditionB          3         NA      NA       NA
x                  NA         NA      NA       NA
conditionB:x       NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1,     Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 1 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

Notice that the model fit suffers from singularities, as we're trying to estimate 4 regression coefficients plus the error standard deviation using just 2 observations.

The singularities would persist even if we observed this subject twice - rather than once - under each condition. However, if we observed the subject 3 times under each condition, we would get rid of singularities:

```
y <- c(4, 7, 3, 5, 1, 2)
condition <- c("A", "B", "A","B","A","B")
condition <- factor(condition)
x <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5)

m2 <- lm(y ~ condition*x)
summary(m2)
```

Here is the corresponding R output for this second example, from which the singularities have disappeared:

```
>     summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ condition * x)

Residuals:
    1       2       3       4       5       6 
1.3333  2.3333 -0.6667 -1.1667 -0.6667 -1.1667 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     4.667      3.555   1.313    0.320
conditionB      6.000      7.601   0.789    0.513
x             -10.000     16.457  -0.608    0.605
conditionB:x   -5.000     23.274  -0.215    0.850

Residual standard error: 2.327 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5357,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1607 
F-statistic: 0.7692 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.6079
```

Of course, the mixed effects model does not fit unrelated, separate linear regression models for each subject - it fits "related" models whose intercepts and/or slopes deviate randomly about a typical intercept and/or slope, such that the random deviations from the typical intercept and/or typical slope follow a Normal distribution with mean zero and some unknown standard deviation.

Even so, my intuition suggests that the mixed effects model is struggling with the small amount of observations - just 2 - available for each subject.  The more the model is loaded with random slopes, the more it probably struggles.  I suspect that, if each subject contributed 6 observations instead of 2 (that is, 3 per condition), it would no longer struggle to accommodate all of the random slopes.

It seems to me that this could be (?) a case where the current study design does not support the complex modelling ambitions - to support those ambitions, more observations would be needed under each condition for each subject (or at least for some of the subjects?). This is just my intuition so I hope others can add their insights to my observations above. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have to correct you - each participant has 30 observation for both X and Y, in both A and B conditions!

Comment: Oh, that was not indicated in your initial answer so it would have been impossible for me to guess how many observations per subject and condition you actually have.  There is something else going on then.  Did you try standardizing your X variable? Does that help the lme fit?  Also, did you look at plots of Y vs. X (or standardized X) for Condition = A vs. Condition = B separately for each subject?  That might give you additional clues as to what is going on.

Comment: I did not standardize x because it is reaction time data and it is important for interpretation of the regression coefficient. However, the data were centralized. I will look into individual plots, and see...

Comment: @User33268 I'm a little late to the party, but you can still interpret standardized coefficients, you just have to store the values used for scaling and then backtransform after running the model.