# "singular fit" with lme4's glmer

Tags: lme4-nlme

I have the following data frame and the following two models with `lme4`'s Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models (`glmer`):

```
df <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CCF", 
"UN"), class = "factor"), random = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1.6", 
"2", "3.2", "5", NA), class = "factor"), continuous1 = c(53.1859431331665, 
53.9920752359492, 52.2060995286371, 52.7309097715147, 52.9687621513265, 
52.7792820518053, 53.324237379658, 53.0769265513933, 52.562144337307, 
52.9159833925859, 52.9851480591277, 53.2108929763236, 52.5627005607629, 
52.6586547788481, 52.9528178963356, 52.8751803009764, 52.0389070727281, 
53.4611376738915, 53.4516478896541, 52.9340159927059, 53.0960900649167, 
52.7185163546668, 52.5277022312295, 53.4332374842224, 52.7286868682608, 
52.5427283883897, 50.5643976998344, 54.5119621732914, 54.8752697204122, 
52.3895192119411, 52.6623860459687, 53.2895954023616, 52.7207909990632, 
52.3422155906552, 51.7977738690975), continuous2 = c(1.64153094886205, 
3.91593723271292, 1.94039630728038, 2.81456503996437, 1.07971524769264, 
1.67711446647817, 1.92137892126384, 1.96087397451467, 2.21602000526086, 
1.45794117443253, 2.75353217433675, 5.36536076058866, 0.833434180091457, 
3.65998714174906, 2.56715261161435, 1.37475468782539, 1.13569710795522, 
1.32327007970416, 1.14942423621912, 1.47707078226047, 2.7508022340832, 
3.5764241495006, 2.3070166819956, 2.49896565066211, 4.36424795471221, 
2.13701784901259, 1.98293342019671, 5.03952187899644, 2.99575072457674, 
2.63204944520792, 3.38134648323956, 2.0556994322415, 2.66809379088059, 
2.19167325121191, 2.22274607227071)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(61L, 
62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 
132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L))
```

Model one:

```
library(lme4)
model1<- glmer ((continuous1) ~  treatment + (1|random), 
REML = TRUE, data = df, family = Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

Model two:

```
 model2<- glmer ((continuous2) ~  treatment + (1|random), 
REML = TRUE, data = df, family = Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

What I would like to know is why `isSingular(model1)` returns "TRUE" whereas `isSingular(model2)` returns "FALSE"?

This is an experiment with two plots (the treatments). Please consider that my `random` effect is only applicable within one `treatment`. This is because the `treatment` with `random` values was subject to an earlier experiment which I am not interested in, but I want to account for in the model. That is why `random` has "NA"s in `treatment` "UN"

Comment: Can you please run a summary.merMod() or VarCorr.merMod() for both model1 and model2 and show us the outputs?

Comment: the variance of the random effect = 0 in model1, I suppose a lmerTest step() would deal with the issue?