# UPDATED: Multiple lme models or MANOVA with random effects? Problem with singular fit

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-variable, manova

hope you can help me with this issue!
In my study I have 4 outcome variables which correspond to the ratings I collected for 4 different psychological dimensions (liking, comfort, approach, attractiveness). The 4 psychological dimensions are defined in the column ‘ratetype’ and the column 'ratings' reports the score. I also have 2 independent variables: 'paintingtype', which is a categorical variable with 3 experimental conditions, and ArtInterest, which is the self-rated measure on a 5-points Liker scale. 
This is my data structure:

```
Observations: 7,872
Variables: 14
$ X              <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16…
$ PID                  <fct> 571b712f5d40840009c44804, 5798f7a116020100010411ac, 5…
$ ArtInterest    <int> 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5,…
$ ratings              <int> 15, 72, 21, 80, 91, 13, 58, 36, 18, 70, 10, 49, 82, 1…
$ ratetype       <fct> Liking, Liking, Liking, Liking, Liking, Liking, Likin…
$ paintingtype     <fct> Angular, Angular, Angular, Angular, Angular, Angular,…
$ paintingID    <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
```

At the moment I subsetted the data in 4 different datasets with the following code:

```
# # Select data for ‘LIKING’
Liking <- subset(mdata, ratetype == "Liking",
                   select=c("PID", “ArtInterest", "ratings",
                            "paintingtype", "paintingID" ))
```

This is the data structure of the subsetted dataset:

```
$ PID          <fct> 571b712f5d40840009c44804, 5798f7a116020100010411…
$ ArtInterest  <int> 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, …
$ ratings      <int> 15, 72, 21, 80, 91, 13, 58, 36, 18, 70, 10, 49, …
$ paintingtype <fct> Angular, Angular, Angular, Angular, Angular, Ang…
$ paintingID   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
```

and then run 4 different analysis with the model below:

```
m1 <-  lme(ratings ~ paintingtype:ArtInterest, random= (~1|PID/paintingID), data=Liking, method = "ML")
```

Q1: Would be better to run one single MANOVA instead of 4 different lme models?
Q2: As every participant ('PID') rated 16 items ('paintingID') for every experimental condition, how can I control for the random effect of those two variables in the MANOVA?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**
Following the suggestions in the comments, I built the following model:

```
m <- lmer(ratings ~ paintingtype + ArtInterest + ratetype + (ratetype | PID/paintingID) , data=mdata)
```

however I receive the following warning message:

```
singular fit
```

What does it mean? Should I worry about it?
Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: You can always run a manova as a multilevel model. I don't quite understand your model -wnat are the 4 datasets? Perhaps include your subset command.

Comment: @JeremyMiles thanks for your suggestion. I updated the question as you suggested

Comment: @JeremyMiles I am not sure how to run a MANOVA as multilevel model: are you suggesting to add 'ratetype' as a fixed effect in my model?

Comment: Here's an article about it. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-20585-4_16 . I'm fairly sure that the book Serious Stats by Baguley covers it (as do many others).

Comment: @JeremyMiles thanks

Comment: About singular fits: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models

Comment: TL;DR Your model is too complex

Comment: Thanks everyone for your useful comments. I decided to run 4 different models for each of my outcome variable to avoid building a model that is too complex

Answer (score 1):

A short answer to the updated question: your model is too complex. You will need to either simplify your model (typically one removes more complex random effects) or to switch to a Bayesian approach to fitting your model. A more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/379068/121522).

Comment: thanks for the link. I am considering running a simple repeated-measures ANOVA using the 'aov' function in R, which might be enough to model my data.

Comment: @Nicole You can start by removing the random slopes, and then simplify it further as needed.