# Binomial glmer() singular despite "lots" of data

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have been reading different questions about how easy it is to bump into singularities when fitting mixed effects models with `glmer()`. In general, the idea is that singularities might arise from very complex random structures. If the random structure is simple, it might also happen when the data is not enough to calculate the variance-covariance matrix... see for example [this page by Ben Bolker](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1), [Robert Long's answer to this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models) or the [help page of `isSingular()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/isSingular.html).

However, the model I'm trying to fit is very simple:

```
mod.detection_rand <- glmer(reaction ~ Pedra + (1|Channel), family="binomial", data = garotes)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

... and apparently I have enough data for the different (fixed and random) predictor variable combinations:

```
library(tidyverse)
garotes %>% 
  group_by(Channel, Pedra) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   Channel [8]
   Channel Pedra     n
     <int> <fct> <int>
 1       1 No       13
 2       1 Yes      13
 3       2 No       14
 4       2 Yes      12
 5       3 No       12
 6       3 Yes      14
 7       4 No       13
 8       4 Yes      13
 9       5 No       13
10       5 Yes      13
11       6 No       14
12       6 Yes      12
13       7 No       13
14       7 Yes      13
15       8 No       14
16       8 Yes      12
```

What do you think?

EDIT: Here's the summary of the model, `summary(mod.detection_rand)`

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: reaction ~ Pedra + (1 | Channel)
   Data: garotes

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   261.5    271.5   -127.7    255.5      205 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8533 -0.9449  0.5396  0.5396  1.0583 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Channel (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 208, groups:  Channel, 8

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -0.1133     0.1946  -0.582     0.56    
PedraYes      1.3473     0.3066   4.394 1.11e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
PedraYes -0.635
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

EDIT2:
Following Billy's comment:

```
bobyqa : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
Nelder_Mead : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
nlminbwrap : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
nmkbw : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
optimx.L-BFGS-B : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA : boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
[OK]
```

EDIT3: Following Isabella's answer:

I checked the structure of the outcome variable (`reaction`). Here's the table of outcomes:

```
library(tidyverse)
garotes %>% 
  group_by(Channel, Pedra, reaction) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  print(n = Inf)
# A tibble: 32 x 4
# Groups:   Channel, Pedra [16]
    Channel Pedra   reaction  n
      <int> <fct>    <int>  <int>
 1       1 No           0     6
 2       1 No           1     7
 3       1 Yes          0     3
 4       1 Yes          1    10
 5       2 No           0     7
 6       2 No           1     7
 7       2 Yes          0     2
 8       2 Yes          1    10
 9       3 No           0     8
10       3 No           1     4
11       3 Yes          0     6
12       3 Yes          1     8
13       4 No           0     7
14       4 No           1     6
15       4 Yes          0     3
16       4 Yes          1    10
17       5 No           0     8
18       5 No           1     5
19       5 Yes          0     1
20       5 Yes          1    12
21       6 No           0     6
22       6 No           1     8
23       6 Yes          0     2
24       6 Yes          1    10
25       7 No           0     6
26       7 No           1     7
27       7 Yes          0     2
28       7 Yes          1    11
29       8 No           0     8
30       8 No           1     6
31       8 Yes          0     4
32       8 Yes          1     8
```

Apparently, there are both types of outcomes for all `Channels` and all `Pedra`treatments... so it is not like the example Isabella presented... furthermore, I tried to model this GLMM with the `library(GLMMadaptive)` and it did not converge either.

EDIT4: The data set I'm using, in case someone's curious.

```
Channel Pedra   reaction
1   No  1
2   No  0
3   No  0
4   No  0
5   No  0
6   No  1
7   No  0
8   No  0
1   No  1
2   No  1
3   No  1
4   No  1
5   No  0
6   No  0
7   No  0
8   No  0
1   No  0
2   No  1
3   No  0
4   No  0
5   No  0
6   No  0
7   No  0
8   No  1
1   No  0
2   No  1
3   Yes 0
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 0
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 0
4   Yes 0
5   No  0
6   No  1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 0
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 1
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 0
7   No  1
8   No  1
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 1
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 1
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 0
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 0
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 0
8   Yes 0
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 0
4   Yes 0
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 0
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 0
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 0
8   Yes 0
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 0
3   Yes 1
4   Yes 0
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 0
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 0
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 1
2   Yes 1
3   Yes 1
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 0
2   Yes 0
3   Yes 1
4   Yes 1
5   Yes 1
6   Yes 1
7   Yes 1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 1
2   No  0
3   Yes 1
4   No  1
5   Yes 1
6   No  1
7   Yes 1
8   No  1
1   No  0
2   Yes 1
3   No  0
4   Yes 1
5   No  1
6   Yes 1
7   No  1
8   Yes 1
1   Yes 0
2   No  1
3   Yes 1
4   No  0
5   Yes 1
6   No  1
7   Yes 1
8   No  0
1   No  0
2   No  1
3   No  1
4   No  0
5   No  1
6   No  0
7   No  0
8   No  0
1   No  1
5   No  0
3   No  1
4   No  1
2   No  1
6   No  0
7   No  1
8   No  0
1   No  0
5   No  0
3   No  0
4   No  0
2   No  1
6   No  0
7   No  0
8   No  0
1   No  1
5   No  1
3   No  1
4   No  0
2   No  0
6   No  1
7   No  1
8   No  0
1   No  1
5   No  0
3   No  0
4   No  1
2   No  0
6   No  1
7   No  1
8   No  1
1   No  1
5   No  1
3   No  0
4   No  1
2   No  0
6   No  1
7   No  1
8   No  1
1   No  1
5   No  1
3   No  0
4   No  0
2   No  0
6   No  1
7   No  0
8   No  0
1   No  0
5   No  0
3   No  0
4   No  1
2   No  0
6   No  0
7   No  1
8   No  1
```

Thank you very much for all of your responses, in any case! Learning a lot from them!

Comment: If you include the output of `summary(mod.detection_rand)`, we can usually see why it singular.

Comment: Thanks Eoin, just edited the main question to include the `summary(mod.detection_rand)`.

Comment: The following seems to work: `mixed_model(reaction ~ Pedra , random = ~ 1 | Channel, data = DF, family = binomial(), iter_EM = 200)`

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos it works! Ha! But... why was it so difficult to make it converge? Any hypothesis? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A further comment: I took a look at your data, and it's clear, again,
that there is no evidence of systematic variance between the different channels.
This is why the mixed model estimates the between-channel variance to be $0$,
making the model singular.

You can see this in the figure below, where the standard errors for almost every channel overlap...

[image]

...and can confirm it by ANOVA decomposition of a fixed-effects GLM, showing that there is no significant main effect of Channel (p = .986).

```r
m_fixed_effects = glm(cbind(n, total) ~ Pedra + factor(Channel), 
                      data=positive, family=binomial)
car::Anova(m_fixed_effects)
# Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
# 
# Response: cbind(n, total)
#                 LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
# Pedra             4.9148  1    0.02663 *
# factor(Channel)   1.3859  7    0.98600  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### Code

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = read.csv('/path/to/reaction.csv')
head(df)
#   Channel Pedra reaction  n
# 1       1    No        0  6
# 2       1    No        1  7
# 3       1   Yes        0  3
# 4       1   Yes        1 10
# 5       2    No        0  7
# 6       2    No        1  7

df = df %>%
  group_by(Channel, Pedra) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(n),
         prop = n / total,
         se = sqrt((prop * (1-prop)) / n)) %>%
  ungroup()
positive = filter(df, reaction==1)

ggplot(positive, aes(Pedra, prop, group=Channel, color=factor(Channel))) +
  geom_path(position = position_dodge(width=.1)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=.1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, group=1, color='black',
               position = position_nudge(x=c(-.2, .2))) +
  geom_linerange(mapping=aes(ymin=prop-se, ymax=prop+se),
                 position = position_dodge(width=.1)) +
  geom_hline(linetype='dashed', yintercept=.5) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1)) +
  labs(color='Channel',  y='Proportion positive reactions', 
       caption='Error bars show SEM')

m_fixed_effects = glm(cbind(n, total) ~ Pedra + factor(Channel), 
                      data=positive, family=binomial)
car::Anova(m_fixed_effects)
# Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
# 
# Response: cbind(n, total)
#                 LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
# Pedra             4.9148  1    0.02663 *
# factor(Channel)   1.3859  7    0.98600  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Good work, nice answer (+1)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @Eoin, that's a very clear way to show it. Thanks again for your answer and for your time!

Answer (score 9):

Isabella made some excellent points. This can also  happen when there is very little variation at the channel level. Perhaps channels are just very similar to each other so their variance really is close to zero  and therefore not needed in the model. You can assess this by fitting a glm and see if the inferences are similar.

Comment: In fact, this is what the output of `summary(mod.detection_rand)` is telling us. The model estimates that the variance in intercepts across the different channels (in the random effects block) is $0$. In other words, there are apparently no systematic differences between channels once the effect of `Pedra` has been taken into account.

Comment: @Eoin yes, that's exactly what I meant, but Isabella also pointed out that this can happen due to data sparsity and in my experience it can happen for unknown reasons when there is actual variation.

Comment: Agreed, but we can see from the fixed effects and the balanced design that sparsity isn't the problem here (unless some very exotic contrasts were used for `Pedra`).

Comment: @Eoin and @Robert, I don't think variance at the `Channel` level is 0. This must be some kind of artifact. In fact, there are big differences across channels, that's why we decided to include them as a random effect... weird... anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @JordiPagès yes that's what I meant in my last comment. Have you tried increasing nAGQ > 1 ? Also have you tried other packages apart from GLMMAdaptive, or setting different start points in the optimizer ? Can you share the data itself ?

Comment: @RobertLong yes, thanks. I've tried with `nAGQ` > 1 using `lme4::glmer()` and using `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model()`. It never converges. I haven't tried different start points for the optimizer... I will try that. Of course I can share the data. I will attach it at the end of the original question. Cheers!

Comment: I've looked again at this, including your data, and can confirm that there is no evidence of any variance between the channels. I've included this as a [new answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/488585/42952).

Answer (score 7):

Because this is a mixed effects binary logistic regression model, it assumes that your outcome variable is binary with values coded as either 0 or 1.

What you need to investigate is whether you have enough 1's present in your response variable for a sufficient number of 'subjects'. (In your case, subject stands for channel.)

Here is a made-up example which produces the same warning as wnat you got:

```
SubjectID <- rep(1:5, each = 3)
SubjectID

Outcome <- rep(0, 15)
Outcome[1] <- 1

Data <- data.frame(Outcome, SubjectID)
str(Data)

Data

library(lme4)

glmer(Outcome ~ 1 + (1|SubjectID), family="binomial", data = Data)
```

In this example, there are 5 subjects such that 4 of them have only 0 outcome values and one of them has outcome values which include a single value of 1. (Each subject has 3 outcome values in total.)

Even if you give each of the subject in this made-up example a value of 1 for their first outcome value, you will still get the same error message when fitting the model:

```
Outcome <- rep(0, 15)

Outcome[c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13)] <- 1
```

However, if all 4 subjects who initially had only 0 values are allowed to keep these values and the first subject receives two values of 1, the error message disappears:

```
Outcome <- rep(0, 15)

Outcome[c(1,2)] <- 1
```

Once you understand better the pattern of 0 and 1 values for the outcome variable among your study subjects, the other thing you can try is fitting your model with the *mixed_model()* function from the **GLMMadaptive** package in R.

For the small example provided here, this function would be used like this:

```
library(GLMMadaptive)

m <- mixed_model(fixed = Outcome ~ 1, 
                 random = ~ 1 | SubjectID, 
                 data = Data,
                 family = binomial())
summary(m)
```

Comment: Fantastic! I will definitively try that! Cheers!

Comment: the only big difference between `lme4::glmer` and `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model` is the *default* number of quadrature points (1 for `glmer`, 11 for `mixed_model` in this case); you can adjust this with `nAGQ` (in either package).

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete response Isabella. I have checked the outcome variable (`reaction` in this case) and the `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model` function. See EDIT3 in my original question. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Out of curiosity, does the error arise when you use an alternative estimator? It could be that the estimator is for some reason getting stuck at a singularity. You may just try the following: `mod.alt_est <- allFit(mod.detection_rand)`. Alternatively, you may need a Bayesian solution to help regularize the estimation and force it away from a singularity (try `blme` package if the `allFit` function doesn't produce an estimator that works).

Comment: Thanks Billy. It does give the same warning for all optimizers. See edit in the main question.